# How would one go about selling a large amount of Bitcoin?

Tags: sell-bitcoins

How to proceed to sell Bitcoin in the market when the purchase was made in 2010 was a value of 21k USD.

Comment: I'm not sure that anybody was buying or selling bitcoins in 2009, certainly not for 21k (of what currency?)  The famous "pizza transaction" didn't take place until 2010.  I feel like you might have some bad info.  But anyway, you can sell your bitcoins on an exchange, regardless of when you acquired them or how much you paid.  We have lots of other questions on how to sell coins.

Comment: apologies was June 27, 2010, and it was 21K US$

Answer (score 1):

Open an account at a suitable exchange that services people in your area. In the United States, Gemini (now called Coinbase Pro) would be a good choice. You should not be paying fees more than 1% of the prices you see on bitcoin pricing sites like coinmarketcap.

By my math, that would be about 320,000 bitcoins with a current value of approximately $900 million. (You'd have 320K BCH and BSV too, worth about another $80 million.) But it's hard to imagine that this story is accurate because it would have been very difficult to buy so many bitcoins in a single transaction back when the supply was so small.

Comment: Did you mean Gemini or GDAX?

Comment: It would be a little more due to the dates of purchase..I would like more information ... in Switzerland, which would be the best company option, in this volume...At the time they were acquired it was in the USA, but now it is living in Europe

Comment: @anderson1966: So, you're sitting on about a billion dollars worth of bitcoins, and you're asking for advice from random strangers on the Internet, instead of hiring a dedicated consultant to help maximize your returns?